# JQuery onclick function showing same id of all anchor tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When click on each anchor tags then show its own id. But now i am clicking on each anchor tag then show same id check1 .

```
<div id="test">
        <a class="link" id="check1" href="#">1</a>
        <a class="link" id="check2" href="#">2</a>
        <a class="link" id="check3" href="#">3</a>
        <a class="link" id="check4" href="#">4</a>
        <a class="link" id="check5" href="#">5</a>
        <a class="link" id="check6" href="#">6</a>
        <a class="link" id="check7" href="#">7</a>
    </div>


<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#test a').click(function(){
                var ids=$('a').attr('id');
                alert(ids);

            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Change `$('a').attr('id')` to just `this.id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$(this).attr('id')`. The problem was in the code `$('a').attr('id')` where it gets the `id` of the `<a>` element. Since, there are multiple `<a>` element it considers the first `<a>` element and takes its `id`. Using `$(this)` will get the scope of the `<a>` element that is clicked. You can even use `this.id` inside the click function.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#test a').click(function(){
        var ids=$(this).attr('id');
        alert(ids);

    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">
    <a class="link" id="check1" href="#">1</a>
    <a class="link" id="check2" href="#">2</a>
    <a class="link" id="check3" href="#">3</a>
    <a class="link" id="check4" href="#">4</a>
    <a class="link" id="check5" href="#">5</a>
    <a class="link" id="check6" href="#">6</a>
    <a class="link" id="check7" href="#">7</a>
</div>
```